# How to use square bracket in EL JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I have seen people using square bracket in JSF, and I am not sure if I understand its use correctly. So maybe an JSF guru can help me understand it

1.So let say I have this

```
#{bean.x}
```

and x is a two dimensional array (x[][]), how do I display `x[0]` using EL? I would imagine that I need to use square bracket in this case. I think I use `#{bean.x[0]}`, but I got exception.

2.The second scenario is from BalusC code [Pass Argument to a composite-component action attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355543/pass-argument-to-a-composite-component-action-attribute)

```
<composite:interface>
   <composite:attribute name="bean" type="java.lang.Object" />
   <composite:attribute name="action" type="java.lang.String" />
   <composite:attribute name="property" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
   <h:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.action]}">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.property]}" value="Somestring" />
   </h:commandButton>
</composite:implementation>
```

I understand what the code is doing and it works beautifully, but I would appreciate if someone can explain what is the use of the square bracket in this case. Thank you very much

Comment: For the second part, `cc.attrs` is the map of parameters passed to the composition by the page. If `bean` has value `myBean` and `action` has value `myAction`, then `#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.action]}` would be the equivalent to `#{myBean.myAction}` (but passed as attributes to a composite, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I think I use `#{bean.x[0]}`, but I got exception.*

It's unfortunate that you didn't share the exception details. But this should just work, provided that there's a `getX()` method which returns a non-`null` array of which the given index really exists.

---

> *The second scenario is from BalusC code Pass Argument to a composite-component action attribute*

In this particular case, the brace notation `[]` enables you to use a dynamic property name or action method name. The following of course don't work

```
#{cc.attrs.bean.cc.attrs.action}
```

It would only try to invoke `bean.getCc().getAttrs().action()`.

The brace notation is also used on `Map<K, V>`. It allows you to specify keys which contain dots (which in turn shouldn't be EL-evaluated as properties)

```
#{bean.map['key.with.dots']}
```

It of course also allows you to specify a dynamic map key:

```
#{bean.map[otherBean.mapKey]}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: `I think I use #{bean.x[0]}, but I got exception.` This in fact does work. I wrote a small test case, and it works as expected. The exception was something else. Thank you for your insight