# Date converter using columns of dataTable primefaces

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and I have a datatable witch contains 3 columns: DateStart, DateEnd, and NombreOfDay, I want to get the difference between the DateStart and DateEnd and put the result on NombreOfDay, this is what I try to do :

```
 <p:dataTable var="demande"   value="#{myBean.allDemandes}"> 
 <p:column headerText="Start:" >
 <h:outputText value="#{myBean.dateStart}" >
 <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" timeZone="CET" />   </h:outputText></p:column>

 <p:column headerText="End:" > 
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.dateEnd}" >
<f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" timeZone="CET" /></h:outputText>
 </p:column>
 <!-- Nombre of days between two date -->
 <p:column headerText="Nbr"   >
    <h:outputText value="#{demande['dateEnd']-demande['dateStart']}"  >
    </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
```

but I get this error:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 31/03/15 00:00 of type class java.util.Date to Number
at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.subtract(ELArithmetic.java:315) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstMinus.getValue(AstMinus.java:41) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` operator in EL operates on [`java.lang.Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) only. The [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) isn't a subclass of that. You need to get the raw timestamp out of it via [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) method which returns the epoch time in milliseconds in flavor of `long` which is in EL interpreted as [`java.lang.Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), a fullworthy subclass of `java.lang.Number`.

So, basically the below would print the difference in milliseconds:

```
<p:column headerText="Nbr">
    #{demande.dateEnd.time - demande.dateStart.time}
</p:column>
```

*(note that I simplified the EL expression by getting rid of unnecessary [brace notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343410/how-to-use-square-bracket-in-el-jsf/) and [output text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything))*

Ignoring the DST influences, you could just divide the result by the amount of milliseconds a full day can consist: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`:

```
<p:column headerText="Nbr">
    #{(demande.dateEnd.time - demande.dateStart.time) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)}
</p:column>
```

If you'd like to take the DST influences into account, then you'd really better do the job in Java side, preferably with a reusable [EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function). JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has one out the box, the [`of:daysBetween()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) ([source code here](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/el/functions/Dates.java#L251)):

```
<p:column headerText="Nbr">
    #{of:daysBetween(demande.dateStart, demande.dateEnd)}
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subtract `Date` objects the way you tried to. The `-` operator expects the arguments to be a number (or at least can be casted). This is where the exception occurs. What would you even expect as a result? Days? Minutes?

Do the logic within the bean, i.e. write a new method for that purpose.
This way, you'd have something like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.calcDurationInDays(demande)}" />
```

Given that you have a class `Demande`, your backing bean method could be:

```
public int calcDurationInDays(Demande demande){
   //calculate difference between demande's start and end date
   return difference;
}
```

There are numerous threads and libraries on how to get the difference between to dates in java, e.g.: [How do you subtract Dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526485/how-do-you-subtract-dates-in-java)

Comment: thanks @jp-jee I follow your proposition and I used the Joda Time API so that become easy