# How To add two differents method to the same commandButton in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, xhtml, commandbutton

I have a button called "Send" in a page that has a form, and I use this Form from two differents pages for send mails.
From the first page I enter to this form and I must to use the `methodOne`.
From the second page I enter to the same form and I must to use the `methodTwo`.

Mothod examples is like this:

```java
public Navigation methodOne(){
    return Navigation.NAVIG_ONE;
}

public Navigation methodTwo(){
    return Navigation.NAVIG_TWO;
}
```

and the form example:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel id="email" value="#{service.Mail}"/>
    <p:inputText  id="subject" value="#{service.Subject}"/>
    <p:inputTextarea  id="body" value="#{service.Body}" />


    <p:commandButton value="send" action="#{service.methodOne}" />
</h:form>
```

I want to use the same Form for use two differents methods.

How to use the `methodOne` and `methodTwo` in the same `action` attrubite of tag `<p:commandButton />`?

Comment: is your form encapsulated in a composite component?

Comment: i have the form inside a xhtml page called notificationForm.xthml and I use this page from from other two pages

Comment: You can try with `oncomplete=#{service.methodTwo}` in `p:commandButton`.

Comment: oncomplete - Client side callback to execute when ajax request is completed and It can`t call bean method

Comment: @0x5a4d: although it would be a hack in this case, you CAN call e.g. a PrimeFaces remote command (or similar) in a callback

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a variable on which you will identify which page is open. To set this variable, use something like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/). This variable may simply store the page number, such as 1,2 or the page name such as pageOne, pageTwo. Create a method in which just this variable will be checked:

```java
public Navigation navigateMethod(){
    switch (page) {
    case "pageOne":
        return Navigation.NAVIG_ONE;
        break;

    case "pageTwo":
        return Navigation.NAVIG_TWO;
        break;

    default:
        return Navigation.DEFAULT
        break;
    }
}
```

and the your form:

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel id="email" value="#{service.Mail}"/>
    <p:inputText  id="subject" value="#{service.Subject}"/>
    <p:inputTextarea  id="body" value="#{service.Body}" />


    <p:commandButton value="send" action="#{service.navigateMethod}">
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to create a composite component and pass pass the method expression in as an attribute

See also:

- [Pass MethodParameter through Composite Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358856/pass-methodparameter-through-composite-components)
- [Pass Argument to a composite-component action attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355543/pass-argument-to-a-composite-component-action-attribute)